# Api para deletar não está funcionando, não deleta. A Stored Procedure no banco está funcionando

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Essa é a API

```
public class DeleteCidade
    {
        BancoContext banco = new BancoContext(); 
        public void deleteCidade(int id)
        {
            banco.Database.SqlQuery<Cidade>("exec sp_del_cidade", new SqlParameter("@id", id));
        }          
    }
```

Minha cobtroller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
    public class DeleteCidadeController : ApiController
    {
        DeleteCidade deleta = new DeleteCidade();

        [AcceptVerbs("Delete")]
        public void deleteCidade(int id)
        {
            deleta.deleteCidade(id);
        }
    }
```

como eu chamo no Postman

```
http://localhost:55080/api/DeleteCidade/27
```

Minha SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_del_cidade] @id int
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
    delete from cidade
    where id = @id
END
```

ao executar  pela API(Postman) não deleta. Não dá erro, mas não deleta.

O banco é o sql server. A Proc ao ser executada pelo Sql Server, funciona bem.

Comment: Debugando, você está caindo nessa action da API?

Comment: Sim, caio na controller e depois dou um F11 e vou até o método e o parâmetro tá vindo certo

Comment: Muda o código para `banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_del_cidade", new SqlParameter("@id", id));` como não tenho certeza vou deixar comentário, se resolver respondo

Comment: Tenho isso: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'O procedimento ou a função 'sp_del_cidade' espera o parâmetro '@id', que não foi fornecido.'`
para isso: ` banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_del_cidade", new SqlParameter("@id", id));`

Comment: Muda o código para `banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_del_cidade @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id));` tente novamente, na verdade faça dois testes, esse de antes e esse: `banco.Database.SqlQuery<Cidade>("exec sp_del_cidade @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id));`, confirma se ambos ou apenas 1 funciona, por favor.

Comment: @Barbetta, posta esse último que eu marco. Deu certo.

Comment: o com SqlQuery deu certo?

Comment: @Barbetta, nem testei mais. To atrasado nisso que funfou eu deixei.

Comment: @Barbetta, para o Post está dando o mesmo erro do parâmetro. Fiz semelhante ao delete, mas apontando para a SP de inserção.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81351/discussion-between-barbetta-and-pnet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem dois problemas, i) o comando `SqlQuery` é para retornar entidades, no caso você está tentando executar uma ação. ii) não está sendo informado a variável depois da `procedure´.

mude para:

```
banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_del_cidade @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id));
```